# How to show message that user is already registered in html through php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have an HTML form in which a user enter his/her email id to register everything is working great it checks the valid email id and also registered the email id ! But when I applied new code to check that the user is already registered or not it didn't work !!

Below is my Html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Sign Up - MOBTRICKS</title>
  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster">
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">

  <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

  <!-- Favicon and touch icons -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/ico/fa.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">

  <!--  <script type="text/javascript">
            function greeting(){
                alert("Welcome ! Your Email : " + document.forms["form"]["email"].value + " has been registered under our records successfully !")
            }
        </script>   -->

</head>

<body>

  <!-- Header -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row header">
      <div class="col-sm-4 logo">
        <h1><a href=#>PQR</a> <span>.</span></h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8 call-us">
        <p>Mob: <span>+91-9530803237</span> | email: <span>ab.creations27@gmail.com</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Coming Soon -->
  <div class="coming-soon">
    <div class="inner-bg">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">

            <center>
              <i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i>
              <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>

              <h2>We're Coming Soon</h2>
              <p>We are working very hard on the new version of our site. It will bring a lot of new features. Stay tuned!</p>
              <div class="timer">
                <div class="days-wrapper">
                  <span class="days"></span> 
                  <br>days
                </div>
                <div class="hours-wrapper">
                  <span class="hours"></span> 
                  <br>hours
                </div>
                <div class="minutes-wrapper">
                  <span class="minutes"></span> 
                  <br>minutes
                </div>
                <div class="seconds-wrapper">
                  <span class="seconds"></span> 
                  <br>seconds
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Content -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 subscribe">
        <h3>Subscribe to our newsletter !!</h3>
        <p>Sign up now to our newsletter and you'll be one of the first to know when the site is ready:</p>

        <form class="form-inline" role="form" action="assets/subscribe.php" method="post">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="subscribe-email">Email address</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email..." class="subscribe-email form-control" id="subscribe-email">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn">Subscribe</button>
        </form>

        ***
        <div class="success-message"></div>
        <div class="error-message"></div>***
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 social">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/ashuart001/" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
        <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>

        <a href="https://github.com/ashu271994" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="GitHub">
          <i class="fa fa-github"></i>
        </a>

        <a href="https://plus.google.com/+AshishBharwal" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Google Plus"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
        <a href="https://in.pinterest.com/ashishbharwal/" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Pinterest"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a>

        <a href="mailto:ab.creations27@gmail.com?subject=MOBTRICKS-Signup &body=Please send your query with valid details!" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="EMAIL"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Footer -->
  <footer id="footer">

    <ul class="copyright">
      <li>&copy; <a href="https://www.facebook.com/ASHISHBHARWAL001">ASHISH BHARWAL</a>
      </li>
      <li>Credits: <a href="https://www.facebook.com/ashuart001/">AB-Creations</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </footer>

  <!-- Javascript -->
  <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  ipt src="assets/js/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/scripts.js"></script>

  <!--[if lt IE 10]>
            <script src="assets/js/placeholder.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

</body>

</html>
```

Below is my Subscriber.php page

```
<?php

// Email address verification

function isEmail($email)
{
    return (preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]| [[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])\.)+(ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i", $email));
}

if ($_POST) {

    // Enter the email where you want to receive the notification when someone subscribes
    $emailTo = 'ab.creations27@gmail.com';

    $subscriber_email = addslashes(trim($_POST['email']));

    if (!isEmail($subscriber_email)) {
        $array            = array();
        $array['valid']   = 0;
        $array['message'] = 'Insert a valid email address!';
        echo json_encode($array);
        //   $msg="wrong answer";
        //   echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$msg');</script>";
    } else {
        $host = "somehostname";
        $user = "username";
        $pwd  = "password";
        $db   = "demo1";

        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db", $user, $pwd);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        try {
            $sql_insert = "SELECT * FROM demotable WHERE subs='$subscriber_email'";
            $stmt1      = $conn->prepare($sql_insert);

            $stmt1->execute();
            $result = $stmt1->fetchColumn();

            if ($result == 0) {
                $sql_insert = "INSERT INTO demotable (subs) 
                                       VALUES ('$subscriber_email')";
                $stmt       = $conn->prepare($sql_insert);

                $stmt->execute();

                $array            = array();
                $array['valid']   = 1;
                $array['message'] = "Your Email : $subscriber_email has been registered with us ! Thanks for your subscription!";
                echo json_encode($array);
            } else {
                $array            = array();
                $array['valid']   = 2;
                $array['message'] = "You are already registered !!";
                echo json_encode($array);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            die(var_dump($e));
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Now what is happening when I tried to add an invalid email id  then it shows Invalid Email id in  marked in HTML page but when I added a new user then  add the data in my table and show message but in case of the user who is already registered it didn't show any message !! I also tried to make new functions having **"echo json_encode($array)"**; But this also won't work !! Tell me what am I missing or what's my mistake !! I am trying to sort it from the last 3 days !!

my scripts.js code below

```
    $('.subscribe form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var postdata = $('.subscribe form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'assets/subscribe.php',
        data: postdata,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            if(json.valid == 0) {
                $('.success-message').hide();
                $('.error-message').hide();
                $('.error-message').html(json.message);
                $('.error-message').fadeIn();
            }
            else if (json.valid == 1){
                $('.error-message').hide();
                $('.success-message').hide();
                $('.subscribe form').hide();
                $('.success-message').html(json.message);
                $('.success-message').fadeIn();
            }
             else {
                $('.error-message').hide().empty();
                $('.success-message').hide().empty();
                $('.subscribe form').hide();
                $('.success-message').html(json.message);
                $('.success-message').fadeIn();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You need to find out what did change between the one that used to work and the one that doesn't. Always work with a copy so you can revert to what used to work.

Comment: Why are you using both PDO and MySQLi_ APIs?

Comment: @ Fred i was using PDO API and it also didn't work ! & yeah i have the saved part with me and according to me when i write this part " $array = array();
                                $array['valid'] = 1;
                                $array['message'] = "message";
                                echo json_encode($array); " out side my if - else part i.e inside the outer else then both of them are shown but not inside the if-else !! Hope u  got me what am trying to say !!

Comment: First, describe exactly what happens and the difference from what you expect. Next, include the page/function/javascript, which actually reads `$array['valid']`. There might be the cause if e.g. 2 is interpreted as true/valid. And finally, check the grammar in your app, it's "*You are* already registered."

Comment: When i tried to add the user who is already registered then its not working . its not showing any thing my "SUBSCRIBE" button freezes !! and here is my javascript code !! And sorry for the grammatical mistake !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working. The error was simple but yet difficult to find.  lolz

```
  $sql_insert = "SELECT * FROM demotable WHERE subs='$subscriber_email'";
```

should be like

```
** $sql_insert = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM demotable WHERE subs='$subscriber_email'";**
```

Thank you all for your views. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
$result = $stmt1->fetchColumn();
```

to

```
$result = $stmt1->num_rows;
```

see if that works.

Comment: no in this case it added the new user in my db but didn't replied the message to both the new and an old user i.e again my "SUBSCRIBE" button freezes . Thanks for the help .

Comment: If there is a user which satisfies the `SELECT` command, it returns the rows for that query. So num_rows would be the number of rows returned. If that is zero then there is no user. 
So check if the SQL query is correct. May be run it in phpmyadmin or a test file and output the rows or error numbers. That should help you.